# Lotusscript forall loop failing to set variable

Tags: lotusscript

This is probably something easy but I've been pounding my head against the wall trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  The program is reading one document in a local db, getting a list stored in a field, looping through each entry in the list and searching for the name on a view in another db, once it finds it, it updates document and saves it.  The problem I am seeing is that pdoc (bolded below) never gets set to a value which causes the rest of the program to fail to update any documents.

```
Sub Initialize

    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim pview As NotesView
    Dim ldoc As NotesDocument, pdoc As NotesDocument
    Dim lgroup As Variant, pgroup As Variant, errors As Variant
    Dim collection As NotesDocumentCollection

    Dim nab As New NotesDatabase ("","")
    Call nab.Open( "xxxx/xxx", "names.nsf" )

    Set db = s.currentdatabase
    Set collection = db.unprocesseddocuments
    Set ldoc = collection.getfirstdocument

    Set pview = nab.GetView ("gfmm")

    While Not(ldoc Is Nothing)

        On Error Resume Next

        lgroup = ldoc.groups(0)

        ForAll g In lgroup
            **Set pdoc = pview.GetDocumentByKey( g )**

            pgroup = pdoc.ListName(0)

            If lgroup = pgroup Then 
                pdoc.GroupType = "0"
                Call pdoc.Save(True, True)
            Else 
                errors = errors + g
            End If

        End ForAll

        ldoc.errors = errors
        ldoc.status = "Complete"
        Call ldoc.save(True, True)

        Set ldoc = collection.getnextdocument(ldoc)

    Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite simple: lgroups is not an array but a scalar value. This line

```
lgroup = ldoc.groups(0)
```

Just gets the first value of the item groups in ldoc, not all values. Just change it to

```
lgroup = ldoc.groups
```

Then you will have an array that you can loop through. Same is true for pgroup a view lines below.